# how to Pass C++ Object to C# Class Library

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, class-library

I am working on a project. In that C++ code is referencing to a Class Library which is written in C#. I want to pass Object of C++ Classes to C# Class library. 
So Is this possible, If yes please let me know how ?? otherwise I will have to pass around 100 arguments to C# Class Library.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17189858/1814023

Answer (score 1):

you shoul use marshling.

Marshaling is the process of creating a bridge between managed code and unmanaged code; it is the homer that carries messages from the managed to the unmanaged environment and reverse. It is one of the core services offered by the CLR (Common Language Runtime.)

namespace `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`

Read here a good blog about [marshling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-1-Introducing-Marshaling)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this option, you can add a cpp file to your project that will be compiled with enabled CLR (managed C++). From managed C++ you can call C# classes. You can find and example here:

[Managed C++ to form a bridge between c# and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827102/managed-c-to-form-a-bridge-between-c-sharp-and-c)

Another option is to create a managed C++ dll as a bridge between C++ and .NET if you don't want to enable CLR in your calling native application. I used this trick and it worked fine but be aware that once you load that bridge dll library, CLR is loaded in memory and your process gets "infected" by CLR. You will have that effect anyway though.